# MySQL error causing calculated result to be written to next row

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 5.7
This query creates a new table with the columns order_month and SKU plus the calculated columns qty_mth, count_mth and avg_month.  The resulting table correctly reflects the first 4 columns but the final column (avg_month), while being correctly calculated is written on the next row.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_temp_si_trans4 
(temp_si_trans4id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
PRIMARY KEY temp_trans4idkey (temp_si_trans4id), 
INDEX index1 (order_month,SKU))
SELECT order_month,  SKU, 
@qty_mth := SUM(net_qty_after_refund) AS qty_mth, 
@count_mth := COUNT(DISTINCT(order_year)) AS count_mth, 
@avg_month := @qty_mth/@count_mth AS avg_month
FROM order_trans4
GROUP BY order_month, SKU
```

Please see below example of result:

[image]

I have tried to following modifications to the avg_month calculation line with the same result.
(@qty_mth/@count_mth) AS avg_month and
@qty_mth/@count_mth AS avg_month

Comment: I am sure you can't assign value to a variable, and use that variable in the same `SELECT`.  You need to put the assigning variable in the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
> and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
> results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

You can use subqueries without using user defined variables to achieve the effect you are looking for however. Something similar to the following

```
SELECT x.total_sale,
 x.f1 / x.total_sale AS f1_percent
FROM (
    SELECT s.f1,
    s.f1 + s.f2 AS total_sale, 
    FROM sales s
) x
```

Comment: Very cleaver – lesson learned on the use of calculated fields – thank you